# Liferay CMS capabilities

Tags: content-management-system, liferay

I have requirements to establish a CMS system for enterprise and it has to be java based open source, I found out that liferay has CMS capabilities but I'm not able to find any detailed description of the features introduced on its CMS , also I found some people are talking about integrating Liferay with Alfresco ! does this mean that Liferay is not a complete CMS ? appreciate if anyone can guide me through this and provide me with any resources detailing liferay CMS features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Liferay has CMS features - coming from a portal background the CMS is only one of the many features delivered out of the box. A portal typically is an integration platform for any kind of application. If you ever *only* need CMS, it might be that "pure" CMS products offer a bit more of functionality, however, many people are very happy with the CMS functionality Liferay provides. And if you're not, it's typically easy to extend (this is the point of a portal).

Systems that start being a CMS and want to extend that with applications (who doesn't want that) typically have a different mindset - "everything is content" - and naturally your application feels a bit more like "content". The portlet standard, together with the additional APIs that you have available, is a nice way to start.

For CMSs the way to go is typically a proprietary API to extend it. In a portal, a CMS is one of the possible applications available.

Regarding Alfresco: Yes, you can combine it with Liferay. While Alfresco tends to come more from the Content-side, Liferay comes from the portal/integration side. I'd ask you to evaluate both first and see if you are missing vital features in any. Then evaluate which pain you'd like better: 1) Add the missing features you want in the system you decide for, or 2) integrate both systems and run them both. Of course, the optimum result is if only one of the two is sufficient for your requirements. Then project into the future and try to find out what you'll miss first.

There is no correct answer to this question, it all depends on your requirements, experience and ability to learn and administrate one or both of the systems.

Disclaimer: See my profile to detect my implicit bias - I hope to not stress it too much in this answer.

Comment: Thanks Olaf for the more than enough answer :)
We are more into Liferay from the beginning for the sake of future extension of the applications, for now our requirements are such easy as the following, I think all of them are provided OOB in Liferay appreciate if you can confirm me on this :)
1- Authentication
2- Uploading data 
3- Categorization
4- Administration 
5- Search 
6- bookmarks
7- public & private access

Comment: Yes, all in. Some with multiple variations possible.